# Session storage Not clearing for _blank href

Tags: html, session-storage

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="/test.html" target="_blank">Click Here</a>
        <button onclick="clearSession()">Clear</button>
    <script>
        sessionStorage.test = true
        function clearSession(){
            //sessionStorage.setItem('test', false)
            sessionStorage.clear()
        }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am setting one session storage and on click of clear I am clearing that. I have on href button where I am opening the same page in the new tab with target blank. But there my session variable still exist. Can Somebody help.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `sessionStorage.test = true` directly when the page loads inside your script tag, so it makes sense that it exists again when you open the page.